# Replace comma with colon on input excel mask

Tags: excel, excel-2007, mask

I have a cell in a column, where I enter values separated by coma (`12,34`). I must, to do it this way to be fast due to keyboard limitations.

But I need to replace the `comma` by a `colon`, preferably on the fly **OR** by using an input mask.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you not use `Find & Replace`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for data entry in column **A**.

Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:
**1.** it will automatically run whenever you type changes to the worksheet
**2.** if you change a value in column **A** and the value contains a comma, that comma is automatically changed to a colon

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RangeOfInterest As Range, Cell As Range, Intersection As Range
    Set RangeOfInterest = Range("A:A")
    Set Intersection = Intersect(Target, RangeOfInterest)
    
    If Intersection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each Cell In Intersection
            v = Cell.Text
            If InStr(v, ",") > 0 Then
                Cell.NumberFormat = "@"
                Cell.Value = Replace(v, ",", ":")
            End If
        Next Cell
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**